# Copy multiple content from one cell to another without overwriting

Tags: excel, vba

I must find all the steps containing `"CD /"` and `LCD` from each cell of an workbook and paste it to corresponding cells without overwriting.Here is a sample input :

```
//STEP002  EXEC PGM=FTP

//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*

//SYSIN    DD *

NOLOG *****Dummy Member Include*****************************************

NOLOG *****Dummy Member Include*****************************************

LSITE CC OFF                                                            PHG00280

LSITE TRCC ON                                                           PHG00290

LCD POWER.LST.X                                                         PHG00300

LDIR                                                                    PHG00310

CD /REPORT/CURRENT2                                                     PHG00340

NOLOG *****Dummy Member Include*****************************************

PUT %FILE12,ESDS,F,2000,2000 Industry.txt                               PHG01700

PUT %FILE13,ESDS,F,2000,2000 SuperBank.txt                              PHG01710

PUT %FILE14,ESDS,F,2000,2000 Executive.txt   

CD /UPLOAD  

LCD SAMPLE.TXT

MPUT PHGDFM01.*                                                         PHG00350

BYE
```

I created this sub:

```
Sub Search2()
Dim MatchString As String
Dim matchstrin2 As String
Dim counter As Variant
Dim Name As String
Dim Datain As String
MatchString = "CD "
MatchString2 = "CD  "
For counter = 1 To Range("A:A").Count
Datain = Range("A" & counter).Value
If (InStr(1, Datain, MatchString) > 0 Or InStr(1, Datain, MatchString2) > 0) Then
Data = Split(Datain, vbLf)
cnt = UBound(Data)
    For I = 0 To cnt
        If Data(I) Like "*CD /*" Then
        'Temp = Split(Data(i), " ")
        'Temp2 = (Data(i) + 1)
        Name = Data(I + 0)
        Range("B" & counter).Value = Name
        'Next
        End If
        Next
End If
Next counter
End Sub
```

Its giving me the output but its overwriting the first line with CD `CD /REPORT/CURRENT2` with `CD /UPLOAD` and its giving me only one output.Is there anyway to keep the both records with `LCD`  and `CD`?

```
Desired out put: 


       A                                         B
1   input goes here.....     |        CD /REPORT/CURRENT2
2   ............             |        CD /UPLOAD
3   ..............           |        LCD POWER.LST.X 
4   .............            |        LCD SAMPLE.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
MatchString = "CD "
MatchString2 = "CD  "
...
If (InStr(1, Datain, MatchString) > 0 Or InStr(1, Datain, MatchString2) > 0) Then
```

with these:

```
MatchString = "CD "
MatchString2 = "CD  "
MatchString3 = "LCD "
...
If (InStr(1, Datain, MatchString) > 0 Or InStr(1, Datain, MatchString2) > 0)  Or InStr(1, Datain, MatchString3) > 0)  Then
```

You are not checking for the LCD term in your code